# What Is ** In Python?

Tags: python

I read the following python code:

```
 a=2**b
```

I know several languages like c,c++,c#,java... i even googled ** operator without any results.

so what does 2**b means?

Comment: it's `2^b` (but `^` means XOR in Python, so `**` is used for the power

Comment: Fractional and negative numbers as second operator (exponent) work, too! So you can draw arbitrary roots and get reciprocal values! `2**0.5` is 1.414 (`=sqrt(2)`) and `2**-0.5` is 0.707.

Comment: Same operator works in perl, too. `**` is not uncommon these days.

Comment: If you'd ever learned Fortran you'd know it in your sleep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's simple `**` means power, so `2**b` means 2 to the power of b

Answer (score 12):

It is the exponentiation operator.  In your example, `a` will have the result of `2` to the `b`th power.

Check out the last entry in the table in [this section](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

Answer (score 7):

It's python's [power operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator). You can write this as `a = pow(2, b)`

Answer (score 5):

In that example **  does represent exponation. but **(and also * ) can be used as unpacking operators. for instance when using a list of variables of unknown length as args for a function. I'm new to programming and python so I have difficulty using this in an example. perhaps one of you more experienced users can demonstrate

Answer (score 5):

`**` can also be used as a function parameter to pass a variable number of keyword arguments to a function. Example:

```
def x(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print "%s: %s" % (key, value)

x(y=2, z=3, a=1, b=2)
```

Prints:

```
y: 2
z: 3
a: 1
b: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It means 2^b in other languages. Or math.pow(2, 4) if you were using the math module.

See operator documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: "2^b in other languages" might be ambiguous and probably not what you meant. Many lanugages use `^` as the xor operator.

Answer (score 2):

This means to raise 2 to the power b.

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex